# Re-direct page to fb

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hello I am designing a landing page for my company.. We have ads on FB. we have button on fb when click on that button our landing page opens.
We have 2 option on page one with yes button which will open form and no button should close browser and re direct to fb page.. plz help how can i re-direct it to fb.

```
<button class="btn-yes">Yes</button>
```

This is my button which should be re-directed to fb.. plz help if possible with javascript, jquery.
thanks

Comment: why do wanna close the browser??

Answer (score 1):

You can use this **jQuery** code for your button.

```
$('.btn-yes').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'your fb link';
    return false;
});
```

Add link to assign **window.location.href**.

Comment: we don't have particular link.. when customer scrolls his fb he can see and add in between. there he clicks the add and is re-directed to website.. so now from website he should be re-directed to his profile

Comment: Hmm, if you want them to direct to their own profile, then use this link http://facebook.com/profile.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use  tag

```
<a href="{your fb link}"><button class="btn-yes">Yes</button></a>
```

If you want to open it in new page

```
<a target="_blank" href="{your fb link}"><button class="btn-yes">Yes</button></a>
```

Comment: we don't have particular link.. when customer scrolls his fb he can see and add in between. there he clicks the add and is re-directed to website.. so now from website he should be re-directed to his profile

Comment: @MsDesigner In this case just hard code this url - https://www.facebook.com/profile.php 
If the user has already logged-in in the same window, it will redirect the user back to his FB profile. Let me know if this is working or not. Good luck